# Wie sagt man "who walked over your grave?" auf Deutsch?

Tags: idiom

Gibt es im Deutschen den Ausdruck *who walked over your grave*?

Comment: What does the proverb mean in English?

Comment: A response to a sudden unexplained shudder or shivering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bei http://www.dict.cc/?s=Who+walked+over+your+grave steht, dass die deutsche Entsprechung "Ich hab eine Gänsehaut bekommen" sei. Das dürfte zusammenpassen.